# The Clear button on the ASP .NET Core 6 Identity's Register page doesn't work properly

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am working on an Asp.Net project which uses Asp.Net Core 6.0 Identity which involves Razor pages. On the Register page, while the Submit button works fine, the Clear button doesn't work properly. In the email textbox, if I type an incomplete email and hit Clear, instead clearing the input first it shows the validation message, "It is not a valid email". When I click the second time, then it clears. The following is my code.

```
<form id="registerForm" asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl" method="post">


        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>

        <!-- Register New Account  -->
        <!-- Email box  -->
        <div >
            <div class="box-title">Account Information</div>

            <!-- --------------------------------------------  -->
            <div class="form-floating register-input">
                <!-- input  -->
                <input placeholder="editlabel" asp-for="Input.Email" type="text" class="form- 
                   control" aria-required="true" />
                <!-- label  -->
                <label asp-for="Input.Email">Email</label>
                <!-- required -->
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <!-- --------------------------------------------  -->
            <div class="form-floating register-input">
                <!-- input  -->
                <input placeholder="editlabel" asp-for="Input.ConfirmEmail" class="form- 
                   control" aria-required="true" />
                <!-- label  -->
                <label asp-for="Input.ConfirmEmail">Confirm Email</label>
                <!-- required -->
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.ConfirmEmail" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

    <div>

            <!-- submit button  -->
            
            <a class="login-button" id="registerSubmit" type="submit">Register</a>

            <!-- clear button  -->
            
            <a class="clear-button" id="clear" type="button">Clear</a>
            </div>
        
    </form>
    @section Scripts {
       <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
       <script>
          $(document).ready(function () {
          $('#clear').click(function () {
    alert("Hi");
            $('input[type=text]').each(function () {
                $(this).val('');
            });
         })
       })
       </script>
     }
```

Comment: Hi, have you tried the solution @Mike suggested? Do you still have any concern on this issue, please feel free to share, if you have any more questions on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot submit a form with an anchor tag and neither `button` nor `submit` are valid values for the `type` attribute on an anchor element (https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/links.html#attr-hyperlink-type).

If you want to give the user the option to clear form values (set them to their original/default values), add an actual button with its type set to `reset`:

```
<button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary">Clear</a>
```

Comment: I have changed as suggested by Mike. This time it cleared the email entry, but still validated as, "The Email field is not a valid e-mail address.". I could live with that!